As a master's student, is it better to graduate late so I can get better exam scores?
I'm a master's student in Europe. I'm at the end of the third year of a master degree that should last only 2 years.
I've finished my thesis and did well on all the project related courses and on two papers, one related to the thesis, the other extra. But I had a lot of problems in doing exams,
constantly postponing them or not being able to focus adequately to make them well and score the maximum I could, like I did perfectly for the whole bachelor.
I now have still to do three exams in 10 days and I don't think I'll be able to even pass them all because of the little time there is.
What do you think could be the cause for such mismanagement, considering that I've always been an excellent student since three years ago?
Should i accept whatever mark and try to finish or should I still try to make things well, prolonging the degree for another semester?  My goal is to get a PhD and continue research. The professors seem to be satisfied with my work so far.
I can see that it's not a really specific question, I will edit it with whatever information could be useful

I moved your replies into the main post. I also took a stab at making it an actual question -- feel free to edit if that's not the question you want to ask, but the title should be an actual question (with a question mark).

Voting to close as it's highly individual. But my advice is to seek help from your institution's support team, because you are clearly having difficulties, and talk to your academic tutor or similar about what the best course is in terms of attempting exams now or waiting.

It's difficult to define a cause for this "mismanagement" because it highly depends on personal factors. As @Buffy discussed, graduate level coursework is often more challenging. I would also point out that, in Europe, MSc programs are usually less rigidly structured than their BSc counterparts, which means a lot more responsibility on your part to manage your time well. On a more personal level, especially since European MSc students tend to be older, this is also a time when a lot of other commitments can begin to crop up- such as working, starting a family etc..
One structural difference I would like to point out is that the goalposts have been moved. During your undergraduate years, being an excellent student is more rigidly defined ("do exams well and on time"). If you want to continue in research (doing a PhD), it becomes more about finding a specialisation, learning how to do research, doing research, building your academic CV - and also getting your exams done.
In my option, the current framing re:exams is a bit of a red herring. If you're about to graduate and want to do a PhD, you should have a (soft) offer for a PhD position already. You already finished your thesis and two papers: start applying for positions, and wrap up your exams in whatever timeline makes sense with starting a PhD. Assuming you want to stay in Europe, these degrees are research-based, not coursework-based: your prospective supervisors will care much more about your scientific capabilities than exam scores. You said your professors are happy with your work- tell them you want a PhD position and ask them for help. They will be able to advise you as to what positions you'd be a good fit for, as well as knowing colleagues who might be hiring.
Depending on your country, it might make sense to stay enrolled in the MSc to (for example) qualify for travel grants to show off your work to potential supervisors, and/or retain access to university facilities if you're still involved at your current lab.
Short answer: taking longer for an European MSc isn't necessarily a red flag, since this can strongly depend on life circumstances. But having slightly better grades will not necessarily help you with PhD admissions. Since you wrote that you want to find a PhD position, make that your first priority. Whether or not you should extend your MSc will probably depend more on the setup in your country (e.g. would you save on insurance and be eligible for financial support, or are you paying expensive tuition, etc...) than on eking out a slightly better grade.

What you are experiencing is fairly common, especially among "good" students who never had to work hard previously to get good grades. Something like "natural ability" carries them along - until it doesn't. Some learn to cope and change study habits. Others fall short. Sometimes those (like myself) that learn early that hard work is required may do better than those who get carried farther.
It is hard to give advice for the short term, other than to concentrate but also get enough sleep and exercise, but a counsellor is probably familiar with the syndrome and might be able to help.
Learning requires repetition and feedback. That is why professors give assignments and hopefully give more feedback than just grades on the results.
But, for the 10 days, don't try to get through by cramming and staying up nights. That isn't effective (personal experience).
Talk to one or more professors about your performance in general and on exams. If your classes are small enough they might have some insights for you.
Long term you will probably need to change how you go about learning and be more methodical about it.
And, graduating later will only help if you "up your game" in some way in the interim. A faculty member might have advice about the (new) headline question. Graduating late might cost you time and money but it isn't a necessary block to a career.
